# How are Scribblenauts Remix points calculated?

Tags: scribblenauts-remix

At the end of each level in Scribblenauts Remix you are awarded some number of points. How is this number calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Points in Scribblenauts games are generally calculated based on the number of objects you summoned, with lower numbers of objects being better.  There's generally a 'par' number assigned to a level, and the further under par you are, the more points you will score.